# How to write down a generic genus $g$ curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$ as an intersection of hypersurfaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $g, n \geq 1$ be positive integers. How can we describe a generic genus $g$ curve inside $\mathbb{P}^n$ as an intersection of hypersurfaces?

For example when $g = 1$ and $n = 2,3,4$, we have the following descriptions:

- $n = 2$: a generic genus 1 curve is given by a plane cubic;
- $n = 3$: a generic genus 1 curve is given by the intersection of two quadrics;
- $n = 4$: a generic genus 1 curve is given by the intersection of the five quadrics defined by $4 \times 4$ sub-Pfaffians of a $5 \times 5$ skew-symmetric of linear forms.

As one can see, the $(g,n) = (1,4)$ case becomes complicated, as a generic genus one curve can no longer be expressed as a complete intersection.

For $g = (d-1)(d-2)/2$, we always have a nice description of genus $g$ curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$: in particular, a smooth plane curve of degree $d$ will have genus $g$.

Are there any other pairs of $(g,n)$ which admit an explicit description of generic genus $g$ curves as the intersection (possibly not complete) of hypersurfaces?

Comment: Petri's theorem.

Comment: Depending how one interprets your question it has different answers. For $g\geq 2$ and $(g,n)=(3,2)$, $(4,3)$ and $(5,4)$, the generic curve is a complete intersection (of type (4),(2,3) and (2,2,2)), and those are the only cases where this happens. If you don't ask for a complete intersection, any projective variety is actually an intersection of quadrics in an appropriate embedding, but writing down these quadrics is usually intractable.

Answer (score 9):

For $(g,n)=(g,g-1)$, i.e. the case of curves embedded by their complete canonical system for $g\geq 3$, one has a good understanding of the equations of a general $C$ for $g$ up to about $9$. The cases $g=3,4,5$ are classical and already described in the comments. The breakthrough was I believe Mukai's *Curves and symmetric spaces I,II* ($g=7,8,9$); there is a lot of followup work such as Ide-Mukai *Canonical curves of genus 8*, von Bothmer's *Geometric Syzygies of Mukai Varieties and General Canonical Curves with Genus at most 8*, etc. The main result (quoted from the last paper) is as follows.

Theorem (Mukai). Every general canonical curve of genus $7\leq g \leq 9$ is a general linear section of an embedded rational homogeneous variety $M_g$. General canonical curves of genus $6$ are cut out by a general quadric on a general linear section of a homogeneous variety $M_6$.

The equations of these homogeneous varieties can be written down reasonably explicitly using representation theory.

In a different direction, for $(g,n)=(1,m-1)$, one is talking about elliptic normal curves of degree $m$. Their equations are studied for example in Fisher's *Pfaffian representations of elliptic normal curves*, which generalises your examples for $g=1$.

For more general $(g,n)$ lots of things can happen. I recommend Eisenbud's *A Mystery Variety in $P^3$* in the collection [*Computations in algebraic geometry with Macaulay 2*](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Book/ComputationsBook/book/book.pdf).